# why dynamically created elements will be cleaned in java(android)?

Tags: java, android, rotation, android-linearlayout, manifest

I am developing an aplication by java for android.in my app i create some TableRows dynamically by code.when i rotate or go to another activity and return,my created elements will be cleaned.why?
I add

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

to my my Manifest file by my problem not resolved.

my Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
 package="com.example.alis"
 android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
<activity
    android:name=".Login"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".Mainmenu"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_mainmenu" >
    <intent-filter>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".CustomerList"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_customer_list" >
    <intent-filter>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".SelectProductActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screensize"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_select_product" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>
   </application>
```

my activity:

public class SelectProductActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_product);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_select_product, menu);
    return true;
}

public void addRow(View v){
   TableLayout tbl=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tblProduct);
   TableRow row=new TableRow(this);
   TableRow.LayoutParams llp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   llp.setMargins(0,10,0,10);
   llp.bottomMargin=20;
   row.setLayoutParams(llp);
   row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#eeeeee"));

   //
   TextView tv=new TextView(this);
   tv.setText("txt1");
   tv.setLayoutParams( new TableRow.LayoutParams( 0, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,.15f ) );

   row.addView(tv);
   //
   EditText ed=new EditText(this);
   ed.setLayoutParams( new TableRow.LayoutParams( 0, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,.15f ) );
   row.addView(ed);
   //
   TextView tv2=new TextView(this);
   tv2.setText("txt2");
   tv2.setLayoutParams( new TableRow.LayoutParams( 0, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,.15f ) );
   row.addView(tv2);

   //
   EditText ed2=new EditText(this);
   ed2.setLayoutParams( new TableRow.LayoutParams( 0, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,.15f ) );
   row.addView(ed2);

   //
   TextView tv3=new TextView(this);
   tv3.setText("txt3");
   tv3.setLayoutParams( new TableRow.LayoutParams( 0, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, .40f ) );

   row.addView(tv3);
   tbl.addView(row);
     }

  }
```

Comment: Please read and understand the Activity life cycle, think about your design and problem then try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Android 3.2, you also need to add "screenSize":

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

Mind the upper S in screenSize!

Source: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange

Comment: I do it by see this error:  error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value 'orientation|screenSize').

Comment: @tanhatarintanha
Did you split the code over multiple lines? If so, don't. If not: could you append the full relevant parts of the manifest to your question?

Comment: Do you notice the upper S in `screenSize`? You wrote it like `screensize`. Changing it to `screenSize` will solve your problem.

Comment: This is a hack and a bad one and we should not be promoting it's use on SO.  Google themselves say that it should be used only as a last resort. The correct solution is to understand the Activity life cycle and write code to handle the callbacks, especially onPause() and onResume(). Even if the OP hacks away until the bug is avoided, it is not solved and will happen again for any one of a number of reasons why the activity might be destroyed and recreated. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config